# How the "arguments" is passed through the debounce functions?

Tags: javascript, this, apply, bind, debouncing

I just saw this tutorial about debounce, but very confused about how the name arguments is passed through all these functions in debounce when he use `debounceSayHello("Jeremy")`. Why `debounce(sayHello,3000)` instead of  `debounce(()=>sayHello(name),3000)`? And when define the inner returned anonymous function, there's no arguments there, how did the 'Jeremy' is passed in and finally get to the apply function? Thank you so much!

```js
function debounce (func, delay) {
  let timerId;
  return function () {
    if (timerId) {
      clearTimeout(timerId)
    }
    timerId=setTimeout(()=>func.apply(this,[...arguments]),delay);
  }
}

function sayHello(name){
 console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
}

let debouncedSayHello=debounce(sayHello,3000);

debouncedSayHello('Jeremy')





//Hello Jeremy
```

Original:

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwbjDkSqgss]

Comment: `sayHello(name)` would call the function right then and there and execute it and send what the method returns.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments is an Array-like object accessible inside function that contains the values of the arguments passed to that function.

```
 function sumTotal(){
      console.log(arguments); // {'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4': 4}
      var numSet = [...arguments];
      return numSet.reduce((total, num)=>total+num);
    }

 console.log('Sum: ', sumTotal(1,2,3,4));//Sum: 10
```

Comment: Ah Thank you so much! So when we define a function, like "function sumTotal()", even we don't define it like "function sumTotal(num1, num2) {}", when we call the function with arguments, if we use "arguments" inside it will still work with all the arguments we passed in right? Thank you so much! So for the debounce function, is it correct that: when we use debounce('sayHello',3000), we actually store the returned function "function() {if(timeId....) timeId=...func.apply(this,[...arguments])}" to the debounceSayHello, then we actually called the returned function with the 'Jeremy'..

Comment: And even it's not defined with arguments, our 'Jeremy' will go to the [...arguments] and so we can use apply to call the SayHello with this 'Jeremy' right? Thank you so much!!!:D

Comment: arguments is special object inside function it keep store the arguments inside it which is passed to function.